# Cloth wont stay attached to armature

Tags: rigging

I am trying to make a wing suit and am having troubles attaching the cloth to the armature properly. I have it parented to the forearm and the shin and when I move the arm it will follow it, but it doesn't stay right beside it where it is placed. it slowly gets farther and farther away the more I move the arm.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup a vertex group for pinned vertices under the cloth modifier, and then assign hooks to the same vertices which go to the respective bones. (May need to move the hooks above cloth in the modifier stack so they take precedence.) That should keep the cloth attached to the rig.

Keep in mind pinning is used for attachment points, so a few around the edges should do it, and the tension in the cloth sim should take care of the rest.